# Click Once, question regarding open it with arguments

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce, installation

I created my ClickOnce application witch will install a small windows form application that consists on a WebBrowser control... I need to pass some arguments (this is made per client instalation) in order to open it correctly...

as an example, let's say that I need arg(0) to be the url to open, if I generate a normal Setup I will end up with the .exe file and all I need to do is:

```
myWebBrowser.exe "http://www.google.com"
```

but because I'm using ClickOnce method, I'm ending up with

```
myWebBrowser.appref-ms
```

if I open it it contains as normal the URL and other parameters

> http://www.myWebSite.com/My.WebBrowser/MyWebBrowser.application#My Web Browser.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5f83fa0e3f8a8c2b, processorArchitecture=msil

and I can't pass arguments in it :(

What is the trick for this?

**added**

I do have "Allow parameters" active

[image]
<sub>(source: [balexandre.com](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-06-15_1051_clickOnceAllowURLs.png))</sub>

**resources**

I found out about this [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/marianor/archive/2008/03/08/simulating-command-line-parameters-in-click-once-applications.aspx)... I will try it and post my findings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use query string like normal...

```
http://someserver/folder/some.application?a=b&c=d&e=f
```

The trick is how your app looks for those arguments (plus it must have url arguments enabled in the publish properties) - you should check `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` - if set, look at either `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData` (the first item in the array) or (simpler) the [`ActivationUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.activationuri.aspx) of the [current deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.currentversion.aspx).

Comment: soon I change the usrl of the file to: http://www.myWebSite.com/My.WebBrowser/MyWebBrowser.application#My Web Browser.application?a=1 I can't open the application, saying in the log file: + Shortcut format is not valid. and also + The identity string is malformed. This may be due to a trailing comma, more than two unnamed attributes, missing attribute name or missing attribute value. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007370D)

Comment: Well, you could try including the #My(etc) on the far end of the string, but it sounds like the browser hosting is the pain point. Any chance you could port to silverlight?

Comment: That I can, no problem. But I need to run the application in Offline mode and I found out that I can't use parameters in this way, the application has to be build for Online only :(

Comment: This is not true. When you use Offline mode you also can use `http://someserver/folder/some.application` url to run your application.